# Cross-account deployement in AWS through Code-deploy service

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-code-deploy, aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild, amazon-iam

We have two AWS account say as Dev and Prod. In Dev account,our code build,code-pipelines and Code-deploy services is configured with S3. However, In Prod account an auto-scaling group is running for the production websites.
As per our requirement, We want to deploy the code from dev account to Prod account with cross-account deployment. Basically, The code-build and code-pipelines will execute the code and by using code-deployment it will deploy in the Prod account's Auto-scaling group.

Can someone give us some insight about to achieve the same.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

CodePipeline supports cross-account actions, however it's not currently configurable via the console and requires some extra roles to be configured.

Here's a guide on how to make it work: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/userguide/pipelines-create-cross-account.html

Answer (score 1):

As of today, CodeDeploy doesn't support cross-account deployments. Depending on what your goal is, you might be able to achieve it another way.

**I want to deploy a bundle in one account to another account**

If your S3 bucket allows access to the second account, CodeDeploy doesn't care what account your bundle is in as long as everything can access it. Per @TimB, it looks like [CodePipelines can support that behavior](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/userguide/pipelines-create-cross-account.html).

**I need to initiate a deployment in one account to another**

If you have a reason why the deployment must be in one account to another, you could set up the instances in the second account to be [on-premise instances](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/instances-on-premises.html), though this is not a great solution.

Comment: Setting up the instances on the second account to be on-premise instances doesn't work. The error message is "Amazon EC2 instances are not supported"